# How to sort the answer based on the timestamp after flatten the matrix in google sheet?

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, formula, flatten

[image]

Hi everyone,

My goal is to flatten the Answers in `C4:E7` into one column and then sort it based on the ascending order of the Submission Timestamp, then sort it again from `Answer1` to `Answer3`.

For example in the screenshot above, `Student B` submit the answers at 2:49:27pm, which is the earliest among 4 students, so his answer should be on the top of the column and start from `Answer 1` to `Answer 3` then only follow by the answer from `Student A` and `Student D`.

I'm using `=QUERY(FLATTEN(C4:E7),"Select * where Col1 is not null")` now. I'm not sure how to sort it based on timestamp first in this case.

Column I is the expected output.

Hope to get some help on this issue, any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
=arrayformula(query(iferror(split(flatten(if(A4:A<>"",B4:B&char(9999)&C4:E,)),char(9999)),),"select Col2 where Col2 !='' order by Col1,Col2",0))
```

**NOTES:**

The starting point is:

```
=arrayformula(if(A4:A<>"",B4:B&char(9999)&C4:E,))
```

This repeats your 'Submission time' column with each of the 3 answer columns, separated by a character that is unlikely to be used in your data set `char(9999)` (✏).

[image]

Then `flatten()` puts them in 1 column:

[image]

`split()` is then used on ✏ to get the results into 2 cols, but you'll need `iferror()` to stop a formula issue working down the sheet.

[image]

Then the `query()` wraps around the result to select col2 (where it's not empty), and sort by Col1,Col2.

Alternative with `filter()` so you don't need the `iferror()`:

```
=arrayformula(query(split(flatten(filter(B4:B&char(9999)&C4:E,B4:B<>"")),char(9999)),"select Col2 where Col2 !='' order by Col1,Col2",0))
```

Comment: Hi Aresvik, thanks for your solution! It works perfectly for me. Can you explain a little but more on `split(flatten(if(A4:A<>"",B4:B&char(9999)&C4:E,)),char(9999))`? Because I tried to extract this formula and paste on another cell to understand the formula but it doesn't work alone by itself

Comment: Notes added to the solution.

Comment: Thank you for your detail explanation, it is clear for me now:)

Comment: Happy to help. You can also apply `filter()` instead of needing the `iferror()`: `=arrayformula(query(split(flatten(filter(B4:B&char(9999)&C4:E,B4:B<>"")),char(9999)),"select Col2 where Col2 !='' order by Col1,Col2",0))`